# how to create a variable in conditional express js node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want to create variable base on conditional, but even simple code i can not get the new variable
this is my code

```
exports.productPatch = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  const image = req.body.productImage;
  if(image){
    const newImage =  image;
  }else{
    const newImage = "1598173461682-636126917.jpg";
  }
  console.log(newImage);
}
```

but when i call newImage response is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot **reassign** and **redeclare** a variable declared with `const` (See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)).For your code you can use `let` and then reassign it according to the condition.

```
exports.productPatch = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.productId;
  const image = req.body.productImage;
  let newImage;
  if(image){
   newImage =  image;
  }else{
   newImage = "1598173461682-636126917.jpg";
  }
  console.log(newImage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const newImage = (image) ? image : "1598173461682-636126917.jpg"
```

If this gives undefined, check if your request body really sends the productImage.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `const` scope in the below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.

use `let` instead of `const` like below as @Divin answer

```
let newImage = (image) ? image : "1598173461682-636126917.jpg"
```